# Replacing a portion of a query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I'm pretty green when it comes to rewriting URL's with htaccess, though I can do the basics.

In this case I have a series of query strings returned from a vendor to one of my scripts. That's all fine and dandy, except for when it includes a URL with 'http' or 'https' in it. When it detects that, Apache throws a 403 Forbidden error. I thought that I could craft a RewriteRule that would rewrite the 'http' portion of the query string into something could get past Apache's rules.

This will eventually be installed on a client's machine so I can't change any server settings.

An example URL would be:

```
http://mysite.com/gocardless_confirm.php?resource_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.gocardless.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fbills%2F07F56ERHRT
```

Here's the settings I was trying to use:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$resource_uri=http^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^gocardless_confirm.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gocardless_confirm.php?$1resource_uri=hllp$2 [L]
```

How can I rewrite this portion so I can simply get to the script?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind url you want to get? 'cause your regular expressions is invalid, and I can't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)resource_uri=http(.*)$
RewriteRule ^gocardless_confirm.php$ gocardless_confirm.php?%1resource_uri=hllp%2 [L]
```

Subpattern in RewriteCond are referenced `%#` in the RewriteRule.
`^` is the begin of the hole string the pattern is matched against.
`$` is matches its end.